# How write regex for matches String is positive BigInteger in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have string:

```
String str;
```

My string may contain any characters. I need to determine whether the value of the string `Biginteger and it > 0` For example:

str value:

```
1 - yes
-1 - no
123 - yes
12345678987654321234567898765412243454245- yes
blabla - no
1234x - no
```

a positive number greater than zero which can be Biginteger

I have matcher for positive Integer but it work not properly. And I need matcher for Biginteger

My matcher: `str.matches("^[1-9]\\d?$")`

Comment: `BigInteger` can handle very large numbers, but its range also supports small numbers, e.g. the number `1`.  Are you trying to check for numerical input, or a certain size/type of number?

Comment: you can use try-catch to determine whether a string is numeric or not. and if it is, whether its +ve or not. Or the problem statement is to use regex?

Comment: Please do not ask questions that say "it doesn't work properly".  Instead, tell us what behavior you expect, and what behavior you're getting that's incorrect.  I cannot tell from your question why you think your regex is not working.  Also, please spell "match" and "matcher" correctly; it took me a long time to figure out what you were trying to say.

Comment: @ajb when I write 999 I get fals.
@ Tim Biegeleisen yes I need chek all characters is number and >0 and not 000123

Comment: the `?` at the end of your regex should be `*`. your regex would match only numbers from 10 to 99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an additional case you havent considered in your regex: "0", and others of that form, ("0000000"), which do not represent a number > 0.

The regex `^[1-9][0-9]*$` should match correctly.

Comment: if I write 01 or 0000001 I need false

Comment: ah, then I'll remove the first bit.